# C program compiles with no errors. It displays garbage. I think first while loop may be to blame

Tags: c

This program will create a menu that can

1. take in 2 `char`s as points from a `char` array
2. compute the distance between the points
3. display the line in equation `y = mx + b`
4. compute the closest point to the line
5. exit [program will only terminate when e is selected]

There is a logical error somewhere causing none of the correct output to display. I have been banging my head against my keyboard and I'm desperately hoping I made an idiotic simple mistake. The menu displays too many times so i suspect the while loop is in error. I am not a progammer, but my math should be solid. Please help me fix my logic.

```
int main()
{
    char PtLbl[9] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I' }; /*char and xcoordinates and y coordinates arrays hardcoded*/
    double Xcoord[9] = { 50.2, 45.7, 76.7, 12, -25, 23, 34.6 };
    double Ycoord[9] = { 75.8, 48, 99.1, 14, 48, -36, -123 };
    double temp, m = 0, b = 0, dist;
    double small = 99999999999.0;
    char choice = 'z';
    char pt1 = 'z', pt2 = 'z';
    int in1 = -1, in2 = -1, i, finalin;
    int k = 0, l = 1; 

    while (1)
    {
        printf("a) Enter Points:\nb) Compute the distance\nc) Display the line equation\nd) Find the closest point to the line equation in c\ne) Exit\n");
        scanf("%c", &choice);  /*Displays the menu options, takes in a menu choice, and converts it to lowercase if upper*/
        choice = tolower(choice);

        if (choice == 'a') /*choice a selected*/
        {
            k = 1;
            while (in1 == -1 && in2 == -1)
            {
                printf("Please enter 2 points separated by one space\n");
                scanf("%c %c", &pt1, &pt2);
                pt1 = toupper(pt1);
                pt2 = toupper(pt2);

                for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) /*stores the index of the char in PtLbl array as index1 and index2*/
                {
                    if (pt1 == PtLbl[i])
                    {
                        in1 = i;
                    }

                    if (pt2 == PtLbl[i])
                    {
                        in2 = i;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        else if ((choice == 'b' || choice == 'c' || choice == 'd') && k == 0) /*since points need to be selected first, this checks if a has been selected*/
        {
            printf("Please enter 2 points before making a further selection\n");
            continue;
        }

        else if (choice == 'b') /*calulates the distance between the points with the corresponding indexes in the x-coordinates and y-coordinates arrays*/
        {
            temp = sqrt(pow(Xcoord[in2] - Xcoord[in1], 2) + pow(Ycoord[in2] - Ycoord[in1], 2));
            printf("The distance between points %c and %c is %f\n", PtLbl[in1], PtLbl[in2], temp);
        }

        else if (choice == 'c') /*calculates slope (m) and y intercept (b) to put in a line equations and display*/
        {
            m = (Ycoord[in2] - Ycoord[in1]) / (Xcoord[in2] - Xcoord[in1]);
            b = (Ycoord[in1] - m * Xcoord[in1]);
            printf("The equation of the line passing through %c and %c is y = %f x+ %f\n", PtLbl[in1], PtLbl[in2], m, b);
        }

        else if (choice == 'd') /*calculates the from the line to nearest point*/
        {
            if (m == 0 && b == 0) /*only calculates (m) and (b) if c hasnt been selected yet*/
            {
                m = (Ycoord[in2] - Ycoord[in1]) / (Xcoord[in2] - Xcoord[in1]);
                b = (Ycoord[in1] - m * Xcoord[in1]);
            }

            for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                if (i == in1 || i == in2)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                dist = abs(m*Xcoord[i] + (-1)*Ycoord[i] + b) / sqrt((m*m) + 1); /*smallest distance is recorded and index is stored*/
                if (dist < small)
                {
                    small = dist;
                    finalin = i;
                }
            }
            printf("The closest point to the line y = %f x + %f is %c at a distance of %f\n", m, b, PtLbl[finalin], small); /*displays data from d*/
        }

        else if (choice == 'e') /*program only exits when choice e is selected*/
        {
            exit(0);
        }

        else
        {
            printf("Please enter a valid selection"); /*prompts user to try again if input invalid*/
            continue;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do youi think `#include`s aren't part of your code? Why do you exit `main()` using `exit()`?

Comment: Is `pt1` always `10`?

Comment: no, pt1 is assigned the char that will allow us to store a corresponding index from PtLbl for that point

Answer (score 0):

Obvious error -- you're not ignoring whitespace (like newlines) in your scanf calls, so you're code will get confused and thrown off by them.  You want to put spaces before the `%c` directive in your format strings to ignore whitespace:

```
scanf(" %c", &choice);
```

and

```
scanf(" %c %c", &pt1, &pt2);
```